# Amazon ELB and Apache trailing slash issue

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, redirect, mod-rewrite

Actually I've an amazon ELB configured ONLY with rule HTTPS 443 --> HTTP 80.  I cannot open the HTTP (port 80) on ELB for contract reasons.

I see that for all client requests in https without training slash the apache for some unknown reasons redirect it in http with training slash:

https://host/site  --> redirect to http://host/site/ (doesn't work)

I see different questions about this problem and seems that all people solve opening HTTP on ELB (it add some header informations as well as *X-Forwarded-Proto "https"*)

And they apply these Rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

to get it working behind an AWS Elastic Load Balancer.

For me this automatic apache redirect when is missing the trailing slash on the the URL is not clear (for my understanding apache when see an URL without trailing slash that point to a dir, redirect it adding trailing slash)

Is there an alternative way to solve this problem WITHOUT open HTTP on Amazon ELB?

Comment: If you can't open the port, how does one connect to it?

Comment: I want to use only HTTPS protocol (on ELB) and not HTTP

Comment: I misunderstood. Sorry, I don't know why it would change schemes.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue (albeit on NLB and ALB both). Did we get any solution here?